# SearchWP hook to filter search results and store results in $swp_query object

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom wordpress theme that uses `SearchWP` to search through an archive of posts. I have set up `searchWP` settings to search the content of both the posts and PDF documents attached to any posts.

In some cases this means that my search results include the PDF attachment as a result as well as the parent post as a separate result. I only want the parent post to show in the results. I have come up with the filtering logic to show the parent post and remove duplicates. But, but I want the results of the filtering to be stored in the $swp_query object so that I can access accurate `$swp_query->found_posts` and `$swp_query->post_count` results.

**Using SearchWP are there any hooks I can use to perform this filtering before the initial `$swp_query` is returned?**

Here is a copy of the filtering logic I am using:

```
if (isset($swp_query) && !empty($swp_query->have_posts())) {
        $filtered_posts = array();
        foreach ($swp_query->posts as $post) {
            $is_attachment = (get_post_type($post) === 'attachment');
            $post_id = $is_attachment ? wp_get_post_parent_id($post->ID) : $post->ID;
            $is_duplicate = false;
            foreach ($filtered_posts as $filtered_post) {
                if ($filtered_post->ID === $post_id) {
                    $is_duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!$is_duplicate) {
                $filtered_posts[] = $is_attachment ? get_post($post_id) : $post;
            }
        }
    }
```